# react native navigationExperimental NavigationCardStack renderScene didn't re-render for previous routes

Tags: react-native

I already checked similar existing issues on stack-overflow or gihub, like: 
[NavigationCard will only re-render when the route changes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7720), [Help: renderScene is executed just once and does not refresh updated props](https://github.com/jlyman/RN-NavigationExperimental-Redux-Example/issues/20), etc. But my case is different.

**Page list:**

1. sign in page
2. home page: user can only see this page after sign in;

**Transition logic:**

1. In "sign in page", after sign in, it shall go to "home page"
2. In "home page", there is a sign out button, after user click, it shall go back to "sign in" page.

**My implementation**

I created a top level component called App, and the code looks like the below:

```
// app.js
class App extends Component {
    componentWillMount() {
        const {doNavigateReplaceAtIndex} = this.props;
        let {isSignedIn} = this.props;
        doNavigateReplaceAtIndex(isSignedIn? 'home': 'sign-in');
    }

    render() {
        const {globalNavigationState} = this.props;
        return (
            <NavigationCardStack
                navigationState={globalNavigationState}
                style={styles.container}
                onNavigate={()=>{}}
                renderScene={this._renderScene}
            />
        );
    }

    _renderScene({scene}) {
        const { route } = scene;
        switch(route.key) {
            case 'home':
                return <Home />
            case 'sign-in':
                return <SignIn />
        }
    }
}

export default connect (
    state =>({
        isSignedIn: !! state.auth.token,
        token: state.auth.token,
        globalNavigationState: state.globalNavigation
    }),
    dispatch => ({
        doNavigateReplaceAtIndex: (key) => dispatch(navigateReplaceAtIndex(0, key))
    })
)(App);

// sign in page
// after signin, it will doNavigateReplaceAtIndex(0, 'home');

// home page
// after clicking "sign out", it will doNavigateReplaceAtIndex(0, 'sign-in');

// doNavigateReplaceAtIndex basically is just call NavigationStateUtils.replaceAtIndex
```

**Symptoms**
At beginning, it shows sign in page, after signing in, it goes to home page, it is good. In home page, when click the sign out button, it didn't move anywhere, but when refresh, it shows sign in page.

**What I got so far**

- It is not because of this issue: [NavigationCard will only re-render
  when the route
  changes](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7720),
  because I debugged into rn source code, the shouldComponentUpdate didn't block;
- I am not sure if I didn't right for doNavigateReplaceAtIndex, usually we use push or pop, but my case I cannot use push/pop, because after sign in, we should not allow use to go back sign in page by clicking "BACK" button on Android.
- I think the issue may because of NavigationScenesReducer(which is called by NavigationAnimatedView used in NavigationCardStack), it will mark all previous routes as stale, and will not show it them.

Any help will be welcome, thanks.

**My environment**

react native: 0.29.1
react native cli: 1.0.0
node: 5.6.0
OS: ios 9.3